# JSON format file loading

Tags: c#, json, list

So I have list which is written in my JSON format file. But now I want to load it. For example on my command line `c:\temp\my dir\program.exe test.json` and I expect that my used check box options will be check boxed on my form window.

My write JSON file code:

```
private void SaveConfig(string path)
        {
            var config = new DocConfig();
            config.Parts = new List<DocPart>();


            foreach(var checkbox in _checkBoxes)
            {
                config.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Checked = checkbox.Checked, Title = checkbox.Text });
            }

            var configString = config.SaveToString();
            File.WriteAllText(path, configString);
```

And I am trying to do loading this way:

```
 var cfgstring = File.ReadAllText(@"C:temp\test.json");


var cfg = DocConfig.LoadFromString(cfgString);

        foreach (var part in config.Parts)
        {
            if (part.Title == checkBox1.Text)
               checkBox1.Checked = part.Checked;


            if (part.Title == checkBox2.Text)
                checkBox2.Checked = part.Checked;
        }
```

But nothing happens :/ Need help here :)

Thanks.

Comment: What is a `DocConfig`? Have you tried debugging to see what happens?

Comment: Yes I just did it I write Debug.WriteLine after my if statement and it prints 8times. So something wrong with my if statement

Comment: Did you *look* at the values in `config.Parts`? Are there `Parts` with `Title` equal to either of those checkbox's `Text` properties? In other words, step through the code and examine the objects. Maybe your `DocConfig` is not working?

Comment: everything looks correct for me

Comment: Everything looks working. How to make it run through command line. Like program.exe test.dconf and my program instantly gets my test.dconf setting check boxed in program.exe

Comment: "Everything looks working"... so you *did* step through this code line by line and examine the objects in the debugger? Trace output can be very useful, but is no substitute for actual debugging. You can do this by setting breakpoints and setting command line parameters in the project's properties, then run the program from Visual Studio's Debug menu.